# Vue Call asset script function from component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I am VERY new to Vue, and I am not sure how to even ask this question.  I have setup and installed the [Vue.js Quickstart](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-2-quickstart-tutorial-2017-246195cfbdd2) tutorial and got everything working.

I now want have some javascript that I want to call (load the menu items)  I do not want  (for now anyway) this to be a component. So I have my js in /src/assets/scripts/start.js

I changed the default App.vue script to look like this:

```
<script>
import * as start from 'assets/scripts/start'
export default {
 name: 'app',
 created: start.loadNavigation()
}
</script>
```

Obviously I want loadNavigation to be called when the app is created.  When building I am getting this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/scripts/start' in '/code/vue/src'
```

I try an look up how to build modules and all I get is how to build plugins.  I am sure I am just not using the correct language.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `from './assets/scripts/start'`

Comment: 50 new errors,  but one step at a time!  Thanks @Phil

Comment: where is your assests  directory? is it in the same directory?

Comment: it's off the src directory